# Power BI On premises data gateway login failed

Tags: authentication, powerbi

I have just installed the "Power BI On premises data gateway" but I can't login.
I'm having the following issue:

```
Failed to sign in. Please verify your credentials and try again.
The browser based authentication dialog failed to complete. Reason: The download has failed (the connection was interrupted).
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.RunAsyncTask[T](Task 1 task)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.GatewayCommon.AuthenticationManager.AuthenticateWithSelectedUser(Uri authorityAddress, Uri resource, String clientId, Uri 
redirectAddress, String logOnHint)
```

Any ideas? Is this issue related to the trusted sites?

[image]

Thanks,
Andrés

Answer (score -1):

It turned out be the security level is set to high in IE which somehow blocked the SSO authentication.

go to I.E. --> Security --> Custom Level --> User Authentication --> select Prompt for user name and password